# update column values using CASE returns error

Tags: sql

I am trying to update a column values using CASE. END expression but when I try to execute the statement in phpmyadmin ,the statement starting from CASE word is underlined with a wavy red line, when I put the cursor on the error sign it says unrecognized keyword (near case) the same error next to each SQL key word ,also another error for each entry,it says for example unexpected token (near 'mark'). I checked code many times but I could find anything wrong .Any idea regrading these errors

```
    UPDATE `customers`
SET `name` =
    CASE 
      WHEN `id` = 2 THEN 'mark' 
      WHEN `id` = 4 THEN 'johnny' 
      WHEN `id` = 5 THEN 'bett' 
      WHEN `id` = 6 THEN 'Sarah' 
    END 
WHERE `id` IN (2,4,5,6)
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.  (Note:  your syntax looks fine.)  One possibility is a hidden character that looks like a space but is not.

Comment: try `case id when 2 then 'mark' when 4 then 'johnny' ` etc.....

Comment: Check your column names of your table..check whether table has "id", "name" attributes..

Comment: The single quotes for customers and all the id occurrences look incorrect. You can see the difference with the quotes for mark, johny, bett and Sarah. It looks like you copy paste from somewhere

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? @ehh: the single quotes for string values **are** correct. That's how character constants are specified in SQL.

Comment: I was talking about the quotes of the fields, don't they look incorrect? About the values it is fine.

Comment: i'am trying the statement in local host using mysql phpmyadmin, about the qoutes there is no wrong about them the first one( i don't know what is it called)  we can use it in (table, column) naming also we can omitt it,  single quotes is used with string, varchar, etc..